# recuperar valor id de select e obter o valor selecionado desse select

Tags: javascript, jquery

OLá, minha questão é guardar numa variavel um id e um valor de select e options.

tenho essa estrutura:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" id="results">
<select class="form-control" id="1">
    <option value="true">Sim</option>
    <option value="false">Não</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="2">
    <option value="true">Sim</option>
    <option value="false">Não</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="3">
    <option value="true">Sim</option>
    <option value="false">Não</option>
</select>
</div>
```

preciso pegar o id do select e o valor do option desse select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim se quiser com jQuery:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var id = $(this).prop("id");  // pega o id do select clicado
  var val= $(this).val();       // pega o valor do option selecionado
  
  console.log("ID:"+id+" - VALOR:"+val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6" id="results">
  <select class="form-control" id="1">
      <option value="true">Sim</option>
      <option value="false">Não</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="2">
      <option value="true">Sim</option>
      <option value="false">Não</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="3">
      <option value="true">Sim</option>
      <option value="false">Não</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ola LeAndrade, vou testar amigo...obrigado

Comment: Deu certo leAndrade, obrigado

Comment: Legal Jose, por nada!